# Give array as a function arguments and get it as normal variable in PHP

Tags: php

At first, see my code:

```
//normal function
function test($name, $password)
{
    //do stuff...
}

//calling...
test(['anonymous', '2020']);
```

So, Basically I need a system like this one above. I know that this code is wrong.

**What do I need?** 

I will give an array as a function argument and In my function, I need to get this array as a normal variable.

but is it possible to make these features in another alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splat operator `...`:

```
//normal function
function test($name, $password)
{
    echo $name . ' ' . $password;
}

//calling...
test(...['anonymous', '2020']);
```

Or `call_user_func_array`:

```
//normal function
function test($name, $password)
{
    echo $name . ' ' . $password;
}

//calling...
call_user_func_array('test', ['anonymous', '2020']);
```

Comment: having problem with this call_user_func_array()

Comment: __I__ should guess what is the problem that __you__ have?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. The first one is the best example.